# How to hide/show sections in elementor popup onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, elementor

I have created a popup in elementor for login/register form, it has total 3 sections

- 1st section contains 2 columns with heading widgets Login & Register.
  I gave them custom css ids #login_heading & #register_heading
- Section 2 contains login form with css id #login_section.
- Section 3 contains Registeration form with css id #register_section

I have hided Section 2 & 3 With css, What I want to achieve that when someone click on Login heading then section 2 (#login_section) shows up & if click on Register heading then it hides Section 2 and display Section 3 Which Contains Registration Form (#register_section).

I have tried this jQuery Code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
$("#login_heading").click(function () {

$("#login_section").show();
$("#register_section").hide();
  });

$("#register_heading").click(function () {

$("#register_section").show();
$("#login_section").hide();
  });
});
```

but its not working in Popup click event is not firing, if i create same contents in a page everything is working perfectly.

How can i achieve that while using popup? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use and set click trigger on body section which look to your element

```js
$("body").on('click', "#login_heading" , function() {
    console.log('trigger and code will be here');
})
```